# Root folder file not getting in App_Code folder

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am using this code below to get root folder html file in app_code folder

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/EMailTemplate.html")))
{
...
}
```

But im getting error as

> object reference not found !!

can any one help me..

Answer (score 0):

So the way you wrote the first line, I can tell that you're using a class that is not in the code-behind.  Even so, similar rules apply for how Server.MapPath works.

I think you'll need to get rid of the tilde and replace it with a relative path.  See [HttpServerUtility.MapPath Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.mappath(v=vs.110).aspx)